# Powershell - Export-Csv prints "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]" instead of the match

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

I wrote a function that searches for all IP's in a given directory:

```
function searchips
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$dir = $(pwd)
    )

    ls -Recurse -Force `
    | Select-String -Pattern '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' -AllMatches `
    | ? { 
        $matches = ($_.Matches | Select-Object -Unique)
        return $matches.Count -gt 1 -or $matches[0].Value -ne '127.0.0.1' 
    } `
    | select Path,Matches,FileName,LineNumber,Line
}
```

When I try to pipe the output to a CSV everything is fine except for the **Matches** column:

My Call: `searchips | Export-Csv outfile.csv`

- I call this from inside the directory
- Don't try to call this outside the directory because it will always run in `pwd`. Still need to fix that...

And it spits out `outfile.csv` below...

[image]

As you can see, I'm getting `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]` in the **Matches** column of my CSV.

In ISE the output **without** piping to `Export-Csv` looks like this:

[image]

Every other programming language taught me that *brackets* mean *array*, so I tried replacing `Matches` with `Matches[0]` and no dice.

Apparently those brackets are not an array but perhaps a property or something? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Matches` *is* a collection, but you can't use `Matches[0]` in `Select-Object` because it's not the name of a property. Use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to get values from a property that holds a collection.

If you just want the first match you can use something like this:

```
select Path, @{n='Matches';e={$_.Matches[0].Value}}, FileName, LineNumber, Line
```

If you want all matches as a string use something like this:

```
select Path, @{n='Matches';e={$_.Matches.Groups.Value -join '|'}}, FileName,
       LineNumber, Line
```

If you want each match as a separate record you need something like this:

```
ForEach-Object {
  foreach ($ip in $_.Matches.Groups.Value) {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Path       = $_.Path
      Match      = $ip
      FileName   = $_.FileName
      LineNumber = $_.LineNumber
      Line       = $_.Line
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are the master. Thank you sir